# Laravel - orderBy in nested relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent query like this:

```
Forum::with(['comments.user'])->find($id);
```

This returns a nested result `forum -> its comments -> user who commented`.

How do I apply `orderBy()` on `comments` table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pass a closure within the array when calling `with()` to add further query elements to the eager loading query:

```
Forum::with([
    'comments' => function($q){
         $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
     },
    'comments.user'
])->find($id);
```

Now you have to specify `comments` and `comments.user` but don't worry it won't run more queries than just `comments.user`.

Comment: Any idea how to order the comments by a column in the user table in this example?

Comment: @Vlad
```Forum::with([
   'comments',
   'comments.user' => function($q){
         $q->orderBy('your_user_column', 'desc');
   }
])->find($id);```

Comment: @ggirodda, I did expect this as solution but it does not order by the nested related table. Did you try this yourself? Does it work?

Comment: I tried something just like that and it didn't work for me. Were you able to come up with a solution??

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->data['user_posts'] = User_posts::with(['likes', 'comments' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
},
'comments.replies' => function ($query) { 
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC'); }
])->where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```