# Eloquent oderby using ( with )

Tags: laravel, eloquent

client Model

```
 protected $table = 'client';
    protected $fillable = [
        'client_name',
        'supplier_id'
    ];

 public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'supplier_id', 'id');
    }
```

Supplier table

```
id    | supplier
1     | john 
2     | ace
3     | bravo
```

ClientController

```
$Client = new Client();
        $Client = $Client ->with(
            'supplier'
        );
 $Client = $Client->orderBy('supplier', 'DESC');
```

Error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'supplier' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `client` order by `supplier` desc limit 20 offset 0)
```

i need to order by supplier from with relationship

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Eloquent for this as:

```
$Client = new Client();
    $Client = $Client->with(
        'supplier'
    );

$Client = $Client->orderBy(
  Supplier::select('supplier')->where('id', $Client->supplier_id)->latest(),
  'DESC'
);
```

With this, you're selecting the supplier column values in descending order and then ordering your clients based on the supplier value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your laravel version you can try:

```
$Client = new Client();
return $Client ->with([
    'supplier' => function ($q){
    $q->orderBy('supplier');
    }
]);
```

Comment: hello , thanks for replying but this function didn't work for me + you need to add ->get() in the last of it

Comment: which laravel version are you using @MohammadMansour

Comment: laravel version 9

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the `supplier` inside the `Client`, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571311/laravel-orderby-in-nested-relations).

If you want to order the `Client` based on its `supplier`, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566752/how-to-order-by-column-in-nested-2-level-relationship-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

So, From what I have understood is that you want to orderBy your data based on a relationship's column.

If so, I am not sure if it's easy to do this with Eloquent.
Though you can use Query Build as following:

```
$clientQuery = Client::query();

$clientQuery->selectRaw("clients.*, (SELECT MAX(created_at) from suppliers WHERE clients.supplier_id=suppliers.id) as orderBySupplier")
        ->orderBy("orderBySupplier", "DESC");
```