Sorting on relation table not working in php laravel
Here I want IMR data to be order by according to supplier ac_name if I am getting request for party_index but its not working.
Query in Controller :
$data = Imr::with('imrchilds','imrsuppliers');
if($request->party_index)
{
    $data->whereHas('imrsuppliers',function($q) {
        $q->orderBy('ac_name');
    });
}
$data = $data->get();

Model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imr extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'imr';
    protected $PrimaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    
    public function imrsuppliers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Supplier','imr_supplier_id','id');
    }
    public function imrchilds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Imrchild','imr_id','id');
    }
}

My table sturcture :
imr table:
id  name  imr_supplier_id   created_at  updated_at
1   T     2                ...
2   T1    1                ...
...

imr_child table:
id  imr_id  name         created_at   updated_at
1   1       Test Child   ...
...

my supplier table
id   ac_name    created_at  updated_at
1    Sup        ...
2    XYZ        ...
...


Take a look at the question I linked. Your orderBy clause is applying to the subquery, not the main query. To apply it to the main query you'll need to join the tables first

Check this out, could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571311/laravel-orderby-in-nested-relations

This also helped me out tackle the same issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/help-using-orderby-on-nested-query

@AntonyMN this solution i have already tried it is not working, as it is ordering my subquery but i need to order my query according to subquery.
